# Xdebug for netbeans and XAMPP not working

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I am trying to debug php code using Netbeans but I am unable to, it keeps showing Waiting for connection just like the image below and it stays like that.. I have opned the php.ini and found no xdebug so I added the following lines after installing xdebug and placing it in the path mentioned below.. please let me know what could the issue be .. i am out of ideas ...

```
[XDebug]
; Note that profiler is enabled separately.
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="C:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
```

[image]

Comment: put a phpinfo() and make sure all xdebug values are coming correctly.

Comment: May be this was the awful bug in Netbeans. This type of questions asked [several times](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pJUWWbOzHo3y8Af7kaOoDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=netbeans+php+waiting+for+connection) on StackOverflow.